# How can a linked list be printed after being freed?

Tags: c, linked-list, free

I am implementing a linked list using these functions:

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct list{
  struct node *head;
};

struct list* list_init(){
  struct list *lst;
  lst = malloc (sizeof(struct list));
  lst->head = 0;
};

list_add(struct list *l, int num){
  struct node *point;
  point = malloc(sizeof(struct node)):

  if (&point == NULL){
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    point->data = num;
    point->next = l->head;
    l->head = point;
    return 0;
  }
};

void list_print(struct list *l){
  struct node *point = l->head;
  while (point != 0) {
    printf("value = %d and next pointer = %p\n", point->data, point->next);
    point = point->next;
  }
};

void list_cleanup(struct list l*){
  struct node *point;
  struct node *temp;
  while (point != 0);
    temp = point;
    point = point->next;
    free(temp);
  }
};
```

I dont understand why when i run the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct list *a;
  a = list_init();
  list_add(a, 10);
  list_add(a, 53);
  list_add(a, 66);
  list_print(a);
  list_cleanup(a);
  list print(a);
```

The output will be:

```
66 0x10570b0
53 0x1057090
10 (nil)

17133760 0x10570b0
17133728 0x1057090
17122696 (nil)
```

I understand the first 3 output values they are the value en the pointer value in my linked list. However how is it possible that after looping trough the list and freeing the memory, list_print() stil outputs the correct pointer values and the correct length of the list? This should not be possible after freeing the memory?

Comment: Only by luck. When you finish your coffee, the cup does not vanish until the waiter takes it away for reuse. `free` does nothing to the pointer you pass to it.

Comment: Your main calls "list_free(a)" and your source file defines "list_cleanup()" -- something doesn't match here.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including which includes printing the values of the freed data.

Comment: @WeatherVane Or: If you decide to not drink the coffee, the coffee does not vanish automatically.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad my analogy was imperfect. Perhaps better: you rent a house but when you later hand it back, you have a copy of the door key. You continue to use the house, but one day it is bulldozed for redevelopment, without any warning (since it is no longer your home).

Comment: Bad analogies are like leaking screwdrivers ;)

Comment: @MortenJensen do they drip threads?

Comment: @MortenJensen A perfect analogy wouldn't be an analogy, but the situation itself.

Answer (score 3):

after freeing memory, you make that address(es) avaliable (accessible) for computer in order to used by other programs.If no program use that area it means no overwritten to that area so it remains same before freeing that address

Comment: free'd memory is not necessarily usable by other programs; it might only be available for reuse by the program in which the free() occurred.

Comment: yeah you are right i should ve said it's open to use by other programs but i was trying to emphasize the changing what address keeps but still i had better if i didnt say that

Answer (score 2):

`free()` does not delete or zero memory. It makes it available for later allocations.

> 7.20.3.2-2
>
> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.

However, if a pointer points to an invalid memory space, the result is neither a crash nor a specific result, but undefined behavior:

> 6.5.3.2-4:
>
> […] If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.87)
>
> Fn 87:
>
> […] Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and *the address of an object after the end of its lifetime*.
>
> Fn 83:
>
> 83) If &E is a valid pointer expression (where & is the ‘‘address-of ’’ operator, which generates a pointer to its operand), the expression (&E)->MOS is the same as E.MOS.

Since it is undefined behavior, every behavior including the correct printing of the list is standard conform.

Quotes from: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: `free()` *may* delete or zero the memory. It can even unmap it so the address won't be even accessible.

Comment: It can do so. This is not standardized.

Comment: Also, even using the pointer value to `free`d memory has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Exactly. (But, of course, it is hard to say what the standard would say about a pointer to a freed object, if the standard would require zeroing of the memory. Likely in such an universe, the behavior wouldn't be undefined. Guessing.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad +1 for an excellent answer. For completeness' sake, will you please add a link to the resource you're quoting from :) ?